# Cloud Firestore query works sometimes but not always

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, ionic3, google-cloud-firestore

This has me really stumped. I have a method that searches for items in a Firestore database. It works when I call the method directly from a one-off test. It does not work when I call the method from another part of my app with the exact same input.

Here is the method that does the searching:

```
  getProductsStartingWithCategory(textSoFar: string): Observable<Product[]> {
    console.log('searching for ', textSoFar);
    let endAt = textSoFar + '\uf8ff';
    let filteredCollection: AngularFirestoreCollection<Product> =
      this.afs.collection('products', ref =>
        ref.orderBy('materialType').limit(30).startAt(textSoFar).endAt(endAt)
      );

    return filteredCollection.snapshotChanges().map(changes => {
      return changes.map(a => {
        console.log('matched one', a);
        const data = a.payload.doc.data() as Product;
        data.id = a.payload.doc.id;
        return data;
      });
    });
  }
```

And when I call the method directly from the first page in the app with a test button, it works. That method is as follows:

```
  testTheThing() {
    let text: string = 'Car';
    this.productService.getProductsStartingWithCategory(text)
      .subscribe(data => {
        console.log('success', data);
      });
  }
```

Again, when I call this method I get results as expected (matching products in the database with materialType 'Carpet'.) Success!

But then, when I use the method from another page in the app, it returns no results. That page is a bit more complicated - essentially the method is being called when user input changes. Here are the relevant parts of the method:

```
productCategoryChanged(productPurchase: ProductPurchase) {
if (productPurchase.materialType) {
  console.log('searching for products starting with "' + productPurchase.materialType + '"');

  let unsubscribe = this.productService.getProductsStartingWithCategory(productPurchase.materialType).subscribe(products => {
    products.forEach(product => {
      // logic goes here...
    });
  });
  // rest of method omitted
```

In both scenarios, I see the "searching for Car" in the console.log message. The search text is identical. I've tried numerous times with numerous different search text (all of which are in the database). The logging shows the method is being called with the right input, but for some reason I only find results when calling it from the "test" method. Why is that?

I've tried trimming the input. I do have another collection of 'products' hooked up to an observable, but I don't think that matters. I also have used this exact strategy for a "customer" search and that works fine. This "products" search is almost identical but it doesn't work.

Comment: Can you show the full console log? Is the capitalization of 'Car' the same in both cases? Is this.productService in the same state both times? The issue looks unlikely to be in the code you posted, so it's probably elsewhere in your code.

Comment: It turned out to be an error where I was not unsubscribing from an observable.